# How to create additional TaskExecutor beside TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want spring to load the default `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` from `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration`. Though I want to provide may own additional executor for some explicit side-tasks:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolExecutor myRequestPool() {
    return (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
}
```

Problem: adding the bean above, the `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` will not be executed anymore, and the spring-default executor will not be initialized, because `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Executor.class)` does not match anymore:

```
package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task;

public class TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration {

    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Executor.class)
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Question: how can I still let spring create both beans?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Can't you use `TaskExecutorBuilder` to build default configuration and mark it as `@Primary` and define yours also?

Comment: That would indeed be an option.

Comment: why didn't you put @Configuration on TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: Without the following "hack", Springs default behavior here is to simply hard **replace** the default executor with your custom one. And as a result, also execute any normal `@Async` methods with your custom executor. This may mostly have undesired results.

The solution is to provide the default `applicationTaskExecutor` explicit, like in `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration`. But without the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation, as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Lazy
    @Bean(name = { TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.APPLICATION_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME,
            AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME })
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor(TaskExecutorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

This way, the default executor is always loaded, and additional custom executors can be added to the application without replacing it (which is the default behavior).

As a result, all `@Async` methods will still execute with the default `applicationTaskExecutor`, and all `@Async("customExecutor")` will use your custom one.

Answer (score 4):

The executor bean in `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` will only be created if no other executor beans exist (due to `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Executor.class)`) at the moment when processing that auto-configuration . So , in order to create both of our executor and the one defined in `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` , we need to make sure our bean is processed after `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration`

According to [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-locating-auto-configuration-candidates) , if we make our bean to be the auto-configuration candidates (which requires adding the `@Configuration` class in `META-INF/spring.factories`),  we can then use `@AutoConfigureAfter` to configure it to be processed after `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` :

```
package foo.bar.baz.qux;

@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolExecutor myRequestPool() {
        return (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }
}
```

Then create `META-INF/spring.factories` which contains :

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  foo.bar.baz.qux.Config
```

Comment: That still does not help, because `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(Executor.class)` is still `false` because `myRequestPool` still adds a `Executor` bean to the scope.

Comment: @membersound Not sure why but I just tried it again in my local and it works . Both `myRequestPool ` and the executor  in `TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration` also can created.

Comment: I think I forgot to create the `spring.factories` files. Is that mandatory?

Comment: Yes. It is mandatory because springboot 's auto configuration will only process the configuration bean defined in `spring.factories`

Comment: I have a question.. In the code snippet that the OP provided, applicationTaskExecutor is marked as @Lazy. So unless the applicationTaskExecutor is called for by the application explicitly, then in the order of autoconfiguration is as expected... our TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration first and then the config next but still the applicationTaskExecutor would not be created, as it would find the myRequestPool?

Comment: @KarthickMeenakshiSundaram made a good point, but documentation says that: "However, when a lazy-initialized bean is a dependency of a singleton bean that is not lazy-initialized, the ApplicationContext creates the lazy-initialized bean at startup, because it must satisfy the singleton’s dependencies."